# Update or insert failed, but I'm using a select query

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

For context, the database is MS Access frontend and SQL Server backend.

The full text of the error is as follows:

```
Run-time error '3157':
ODBC—update on a linked table 'v_qryProjectList' failed.
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server] [SQL Server]Update or insert of view or function
'v_qryProjectList' failed because it contains a derived or constant field. (#4406)
```

The code where this error occurs is as follows:

```
Me.subMain.Form.recordSource = strRecordSource
```

The variable `strRecordSource` varies, but an example of a query that causes an error is as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM v_qryProjectList WHERE CreatedTimestamp>=#02/28/2023# AND DisciplineID=4
```

I have no idea why the error reports a failure to update or insert, as I'm not doing either. Additionally, while `v_qryProjectList` does contain derived/constant fields, `CreatedTimestamp` and `DisciplineID` are not derived or constant.

I understand what the error is saying - for example, if I had a view defined as `SELECT ProjectID, IIF(ProjectID>5, 'a', 'b') AS test FROM tblProject`, it wouldn't make sense to update the `test` column because it doesn't relate to any column in `tblProject`. However, the error seems completely irrelevant to what I'm trying to do.

I've tried looking up the error text, but I didn't find anyone else who encountered this error as a result of a `SELECT` query.

Edit: I tried using SQL Profiler, per Craig's suggestion. There is indeed an update query that runs when the above line of code executes. Now that I know the actual query causing the error, I can fix it. I'm still unsure why there is an update being triggered, though. I'm not aware of any event that could fire as a result of the recordsource changing - does such a thing exist?

Comment: The description may be a bit of a red herring (which is sometimes the case with Microsoft's error messages).  What access (no pun intended) do you have to the SQL Server yourself?  If possible, it would be worth running SQL Profiler while you're executing the SELECT from Access, and see what the ODBC driver is doing.  It could be attempting to validate the metadata on the view, and maybe coming up with an issue ...

Comment: Why have you tagged both MS Access and SQL Server?

Comment: @DaleK The database is MS Access frontend and SQL Server backend. Should I not have tagged SQL Server? I was unsure where the cause of the problem was.

Comment: @Craig Thank you for the suggestion - I've updated the question with relevant details.

Comment: The tagging seems correct, but you need to specify that within your question, don't require people to guess.

Comment: Are you sure it's not setup as an "Update" query?  I must admit, I long ago managed to block out things that I knew about using Access with linked tables/queries to SQL Server (because, yucky!), but you do specify a "type" for each query, right?  And queries can be nominated as just SELECT queries, or UPDATE/DELETE?  If you're saying that by executing your "SELECT" statement it causes an UPDATE statement to be run against the SQL Server, that really makes me feel like it's an UPDATE query within the Access database.  (As I say, poor memory, though, so I'll stand corrected if I'm wrong)

Comment: It is your 'v_qryProjectList' to research. It contains something that the ODBC doesn't know of.

Comment: @Gustav Thanks for your input, but I have already determined the query which actually causes the error. For some reason, changing the recordsource triggers the query `UPDATE v_qryProjectList SET DateNextMilestone = @p1 WHERE {lots of conditions}`. `DateNextMilestone` is indeed a calculated field, so the error makes sense. I'm still stuck trying to figure out what's causing said query to execute.

Comment: @DaleK Noted, I'll remember that for my next question.

Comment: Why wait? [Edit] it now!

Comment: "For some reason, changing the recordsource triggers the query" - could it be that the logic currently encapsulated in your view was previously implemented in access code? (See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.form.datasetchange(even))

Comment: At a guess `Me.subMain.Form` is trying to modify the contents of the recordset. Do you specify the `dbReadOnly` option in the call to `OpenRecordset()`? Can you show us how you're making the query in Access?

Comment: Please try to provide a [mre]. There are multiple events that can fire when you change the record source, the main one is `Form_Current` as changing the record source inevitably changes the active record. Access has no clue you're querying a view, not a table, and some columns are calculated, so will try to update columns as it sees fit. Of course, it normally doesn't randomly fire off update queries, only when something needs to be updated, for example due to a child-parent relation with the main form.

Comment: @ErikA Thank you, this appears to be the solution. It was Form_Current triggering the update. Removing the update from that event has fixed the issue.

If you rewrite as an answer I'll be happy to accept.